# Trying to pass Core Data between two view controllers

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, segue

so I'm just now getting familiar with Core Data and passing data between 2 VCs via Raywenderlich.com and I'm kind of stuck on a simple project. I've *somewhat* been able to do what I wanted to do so far but I'm experiencing a bug - I know what's causing it but unsure what I can do to fix it.

Basically, I have two View Controllers: (1) That shows all the items that were added to the list on a UITableView and (2) an option to add an item to the table view.

Here is my main view controller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, 
UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

private var finalItems:[Shoe] = []
var finalName = ""
var finalBuy = ""
var finalSell = ""
var finalFee = ""

private var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

private var managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


//MARK: Functions
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return finalItems.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShoeCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCells
    let shoe = finalItems[indexPath.row]

    cell.Name.text = "Name: \(shoe.name!)"
    cell.buyPrice.text = "Age: $\(shoe.buyPrice!)"
    cell.sellPrice.text = "Height: $\(shoe.sellPrice!)"
    cell.transFee.text = "Gender: \(shoe.fee!)"

    return cell
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let nameToSave = finalName
    let buyToSave = finalBuy
    let sellToSave = finalSell
    let feeToSave = finalFee

    let shoe = Shoe(entity: Shoe.entity(), insertInto: managedContext)
    shoe.name = nameToSave
    shoe.buyPrice = buyToSave
    shoe.sellPrice = sellToSave
    shoe.fee = feeToSave

    if(finalName != "" && finalBuy != "" && finalSell != "" && finalFee != ""){

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        appDelegate.saveContext()
        finalItems.append(shoe)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error saving: \(error)")
        }

    }

    // Fetch a request to retrieve the data again
    do {
        finalItems = try managedContext.fetch(Shoe.fetchRequest())
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error fetching request: \(error)")
    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}

}
```

Basically, I had this thought process: Once the data has been passed through the segue, it would first check if the data fields are blank (Hence, the If-Statement). If it is blank, no data would be appended to the array nor is anything saved to core data. Moving forward, since nothing is saved, nothing should be fetched thus leaving the table view alone.

What's actually happening is that every time I run the app, the exact opposite happens: I get text but with no data and I believe that's because I have `finalName` set to `""`and so on.

Here is the other view controller that actually adds an item:

```
class AddViewController: UIViewController {

private var shoeItems:[Shoe] = []
var addName = ""
var addBuy = ""
var addSell = ""
var addFee = ""

@IBOutlet weak var nameText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var buyText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var sellText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var feeText: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any) {

    self.addName = nameText.text!
    self.addBuy = buyText.text!
    self.addSell = sellText.text!
    self.addFee = feeText.text!

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "addShoe", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
        vc.finalName = self.addName
        vc.finalBuy = self.addBuy
        vc.finalSell = self.addSell
        vc.finalFee = self.addFee
}
}
```

I'm able to successfully pass data over to another VC if it's just a label but when it comes to adding an array in order to populate the UITableView, that's where I get confused. I've tried other solutions (*failed solutions*) such as using a global array & passing over the array through the segue but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: sure no textfield is empty when seguing , also do you hook the segue to the button or the VC itself , also if the ViewController presents the **AddViewController** then it should be a dismiss with delegate to hold back the data not segue back

Comment: (First point): I see, so (someTextField) != "" would be incorrect then?
(Second point): I hook up up the segue to the actual VC (AddVC => VC) because if I hook it the button, I get a hierarchy issue and one of the solutions I found online was connecting VC directly to itself.
Third point: What do you mean dismiss the delegate? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: by default text is empty which is "" , you have to validate the textfeilds for better UX , 3 point ---> is the order of showing VCs is VC->Add then back to VC again or the addVC is the rootVC  ???

Comment: Ahh I see, but I'm checking if a string is blank though not a textField? and yes it's the former. It goes from Vc => AddVC then back to VC